# Static div's for pagination

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, pagination

I have a static div's and I want to create a pagination for this using PHP or JS. Let's say I have 25 div's and I want only to display 5 div's per page. How to do this?

Here's the format of the html div

```
<div class="newsbox">
 <img src="#" class="news-img"/>
 <div class="newsmargin">
 <br />
 <h3 class="news-h3">Title</h3>
 <span style="color: gray; font-size: 14px;">28.9.2015</span>
 <p class="newslineheight">Content</p>
<a class="buttonv1" href="#" target="_blank" style="padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px; line-height: 60px;">Read more</a></div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="newsbox">
 <img src="#" class="news-img"/>
 <div class="newsmargin">
 <br />
 <h3 class="news-h3">Title</h3>
 <span style="color: gray; font-size: 14px;">28.9.2015</span>
 <p class="newslineheight">Content</p>
 <a class="buttonv1" href="#" target="_blank" style="padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px; line-height: 60px;">Read more</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with java script:

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/fSmEL/167/

```
    <div class="pagnation">
    <div class="newsbox">div1</div>
     <div class="newsbox">div2</div>
    <div class="newsbox">div3</div>
      <div class="newsbox">div4</div>
     <div class="newsbox">div5</div>
     <div class="newsbox">div6</div>
     <div class="newsbox">div7</div>
    <div class="newsbox">div8</div>
    <div class="newsbox">div9</div>
    <div class="newsbox">div10</div>
    <div class="newsbox">div11</div>
    <div class="newsbox">div12</div>
     <div class="newsbox">div13</div>
     <div class="newsbox">div15</div>
    <div class="newsbox">div15</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I tried to implement your code, but the code messed up my website.. http://bit.ly/1MO9OlW, the pagination displayed anywhere

Comment: in script file line no: 7 change "body" to ".inner-pages-wrapper" **$('.inner-pages-wrapper').append('<div class=controls></div><input id=current_page type=hidden><input id=show_per_page type=hidden>');** Then you can add your CSS.

Comment: the number of pagination is not working. I have 8 divs but it only displays 6 divs and the numbering is not adding